# how to access assets directly in android NDK - cocos2d-x

Tags: android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I want to read some json files in android ndk ! problem is i could not find any tutorials that describe direct access to assets in ndk (most of them say i should pass pointer from java code to native but i cant use that )
I also tried to find some example about `<android/asset_manager.h>` but again no luck!

Comment: Why can you not use a file descriptor passed to native code? It certainly works if done properly. If you're having trouble with that or via asset_manager.h, what are your specific issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy FileOperation.h and FileOperation.cpp into cocos2d-x/HelloWorld.
Invoke FileOperation::saveFile() and FileOperation::readFile() in HelloWorld::init().
Modify cocos2d-x/HelloWorld/android/jni/helloworld/Android.mk.

Rebuild and run